# Designing an app to classify skateboarding tricks. Best practices for overall system design?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, embedded, backend, iot

On a high level - I want to make an app that can classify/predict skateboarding tricks

Right now, I'm aiming to build an android app that can send/receive information from an IoT device (arduino nano rp2040) via BLE.  The IoT device will be used primarily for sending accelerometer data to a users phone which will then be sent to a server/database for either creating a training set or making a classification on sent data.

I'm thinking of having 3 roles to start:

**Collector**

The collector will responsible for creating clean sets of trick data.

**User**

The user will pass data off to the server and the server will send back a classification.

**Admin**

The admin will be responsibly for creating models and training the models via some sort of regression or neural network approach.

[image]

My main question is whether or not this is a good approach or if there are design constraints or best practices I'm not considering.

I'm hoping to use this as more of a peer review of my current system architecture design

My current proposed tech stack is:

1. Node.js (BACKEND SERVER)
2. Mongo DB Atlas (Database)
3. Java/Kotlin (Android App)
4. C (IoT Device)

Comment: There is nothing particularly wrong with the design. I am curious. What is the end goal here? A product? Proof of concept? An exercise in software architecture design?

Comment: Moreso an exercise in architecting a software product and practicing industry standard development (whatever that may be).  I would like this to be something my friends and I can actually use though too.

Comment: Too broad and certainly largely opinion based I thing for SO.  I would suggest however that a device communicating directly to a mobile device using Bluetooth _is not_ on its own an IoT device.  That would suggest that you could access it over the Internet using TCP/IP.  What you describe looks like just wireless connectivity.

Comment: I might just be using IoT too broadly here.  I think you are correct, it would only be wireless connectivity

Answer (score 2):

@mark-miller, In [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74853557/designing-an-app-to-classify-skateboarding-tricks-best-practices-for-overall-sy?noredirect=1#comment132103583_74853557) you say..

> Moreso an exercise in architecting a software product and practicing industry standard development (whatever that may be).

This is a huge project requiring a broad set of skills. If successfully completed you would come out the other end with lot of useful knowledge.

I don't want to dissuade you from trying but unfortunately, most people would not be able to finish this. Certainly not without guidance from folks who have developed software products using industry standard practices.

You might find it useful to plan out a development schedule. Identify what subprojects need to be completed. Estimate how long you think they will take. Decide what order they need to be completed. For good measure include a list of what skill sets are required for each subproject. This will give you a better picture of how much work you are asking of yourself.

In the end you may decide only a handful of the subprojects are interesting. Do those. It's all good if you are learning.